# GPUImageVideoCamera Live Preview with Custom LUT using GPUImagePicture

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gpuimage

I'm using Swift 3 with GPUImage. I have a LUT image file named: `lut_lookup.png` I have successfully used this with GPUImage on a still image and it applies and displays the result using the LUT filter.

I'm now trying to apply the same LUT filter to the live camera view, but I cannot seem to get it to work. It essentially doesn't even display the camera.

I've supplied my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated. It's probably something simple I've missed/done wrong, but I can't seem to spot it.

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage

class LiveCameraVC: UIViewController
{

// MARK: - Variables

let videoCamera: GPUImageVideoCamera? = {
    if let videoCamera = GPUImageVideoCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480, cameraPosition: .back) {
        videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = .portrait
        videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = false
        videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = false
        return videoCamera
    } else {
        print("GPUImageVideoCamera Nil")
        return nil
    }
}()

let filter: GPUImageLookupFilter = {
    let filter = GPUImageLookupFilter()
    filter.intensity = 1.0
    return filter
}()

// MARK: - UI

let modifiedImageView: GPUImageView = {
    let imageView = GPUImageView.newAutoLayout()
    imageView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill;
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()

// MARK: - Life Cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer().bk_init { [unowned self] (sender:UIGestureRecognizer?, state:UIGestureRecognizerState, location:CGPoint) in

        print("Tapped")
        self.performLut()

        } as! UITapGestureRecognizer
    modifiedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.view.addSubview(modifiedImageView)
    modifiedImageView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
}

// MARK: - Private

private func performLut() {
    print("performLut")
    if let videoCamera = videoCamera {
        if let lookupImageSource = GPUImagePicture(image: UIImage(named:"lut_lookup")) {
            videoCamera.addTarget(filter, atTextureLocation: 0)
            lookupImageSource.addTarget(filter, atTextureLocation: 1)
            filter.addTarget(modifiedImageView)
            videoCamera.startCapture()
        } else {
            print("videoCamera Nil")
        }
    } else {
        print("GPUImageVideoCamera Nil")
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I changed the code to this:

```
let imagePicture: GPUImagePicture? = {
    if let imagePicture = GPUImagePicture(image: UIImage(named:"lut_lookup")) {
        return imagePicture
    } else {
        print("GPUImagePicture Nil")
        return nil
    }
}()


private func performLut() {
    if let videoCamera = videoCamera {
        if let imagePicture = imagePicture {
            videoCamera.addTarget(filter)
            imagePicture.addTarget(filter)
            imagePicture.processImage()
            filter.addTarget(modifiedImageView)
            videoCamera.startCapture()
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone!